# Have a class inherit Proc in Ruby

Tags: ruby, inheritance, lambda, proc

I have been trying to inherit the `Proc` class in Ruby. I know there are tons of other ways I could implement my class without actually inheriting `Proc`, but now I want to know out of curiosity.

I want a class that can be instantiated without a block passed as an argument, but it just won't work ([this](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/24da2db3e1eab67b6ee7be00d75b73beb273a4c4/proc.c#L585) seems to be the reason). It is clear that you can't instantiate an actual `Proc` without a block (not even with a `proc` or `lamba`):

```
Proc.new proc {|x| 2 * x } # => ArgumentError: tried to create Proc object without a block
Proc.new lambda {|x| 2 * x } # => ArgumentError: tried to create Proc object without a block
```

I assumed that overriding `initialize` might just do the trick, but actually even overriding `new` won't do:

```
class MyClass < Proc
  def new *args, &block
    super { |x| 2 * x }
  end

  def initialize *args, &block
    super { |x| 2 * x }    
  end
end

MyClass.new { |x| 2 * x } # => everything is fine
MyClass.new "hello" # => ArgumentError: tried to create Proc object without a block
```

Is there any way (from within Ruby) to go around that restriction in [proc.c](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/24da2db3e1eab67b6ee7be00d75b73beb273a4c4/proc.c#L585)? Or any elegant workaround?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`super` without an argument list means "pass the original arguments along". In this case, the original argument is the string `"hello"`, which is passed along to `Proc::new`, but that doesn't take an argument!

The fix is to explicitly pass along no arguments:

```
class MyClass < Proc
  def self.new(*)
    super() {|x| 2 * x }
  end
end

m = MyClass.new "hello"
m.(23) # => 46
```

Apparently, a block doesn't count as an argument list. You learn something new every day.

Comment: Well, that actually makes a lot of things make sense! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You could write `def self.new *_` to draw attention to the fact that you're not using the arguments.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Actually, Ruby allows you to not name the argument at all, when you want to ignore it: `def self.new(*)`. I assume, the OP wants to use the arguments in some fashion, but for now you're right. While I'm at it, I could go completely overboard and do `super(&2.method(:*))` :-D

Comment: I didn't know that. Learned a couple of things.

Comment: Why overload `new` instead of `initialize` ?

Comment: @rudolph9: I can't remember. The thing is, this has absolutely nothing to do with `Proc`, `new`, or `initialize`. It is simply about the semantics of `super`. So, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I actually dug into it a little more, the block that gets called when you pass a `proc` to say `[1,2,3].map(&proc.new{|v| puts 'v'}` is set in `self.new` and as far as I can tell can't be modified once initialize is executed.

Comment: Crazy that self.new does it while initialize doesn't, would be nice to get a reference or backstory on how you found this out :P